# Which annotations may be applied at Loc1 in the code fragment

Tags: java, interface, annotations

I'm not sure what is the correct answer, please help,please helpplease helpplease helpplease helpplease help

```
@interface Resource {
    String name();
    int priority() default 0;
}

/* Loc1 */
class ProcessOrders {  }

Which two annotations may be applied at Loc1 in the code fragment? (Choose two.)
A. @Resource(priority=100)
    B. @Resource(priority=0)
    C. @Resource(name="Customer1", priority=100)
    D. @Resource(name="Customer1")
    E. @Resource
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing an exam right now or something :)

Look, in java annotations have parameters that can have default values, like `priority` or be defined without a default value (like `name`) in your case.

Now, if you don't define a default value, this is a mandatory parameter, you'll have to specify it, otherwise if you don't specify anything the default will be used.

If you don't define a mandatory parameter your code won't even compile.

With this in mind, among your answers pick those that define `name` and optionally define `priority`) ;)

Comment: So, the answer should be C and D, right? All the suggested answers show A and B, which makes me confused.